# Can't search places like "Bloodbanks" in google places api

Tags: android

I develop app in which i want need nearby bloodbanks data , so any other api or using google place api to get data.

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

you should use [Google Place Api](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/).